# $(f \circ f \circ f)(x) = (f \circ f)(x) + x$

Tags: functions

I have a very strange question in my homework, I'm not sure how I can do it:

$(f \circ f \circ f)(x) = (f \circ f)(x) + x$

Show $f$ is injective

Compute $f(0)$

I can't see how I could possible isolate f(x) here, I thought maybe I could get $(f \circ f)(x)$ with $x$, and replace the x with an unknown function $g(x)$, giving me:

$f(x) = x + g(x)$

However, even if this is right, I'm still lost on what to do here.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It is easy to find $f(0)$ once you know that $f$ is injective: Replace $x$ with $0$ in the functional equation, use injectivity and conclude whatever is appropriate.

Comment: To prove injectivity, just follow your nose. There is really not much to do: Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. You want to show that $x=y$. OK. What do you know? Well, for instance $f\circ f(x)=f\circ f(y)$ (you see why?). Do you see how to continue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prove that $f$ is injective, you can proceed as usual: fix $x$ and $y$ in the domain of $f$, assume that $f(x)=f(y)$, and prove that $x=y$.

In this case, note that if $f(x)=f(y)$, then by applying $f$ we have that $(f \circ f)(x) = (f \circ f)(y)$, and by applying $f$ again, we have that $(f \circ f \circ f)(x) = (f \circ f \circ f)(y)$. This information, together with the information you've been given, suffices to derive the fact that $x=y$, and hence that $f$ is injective.

You can compute $f(0)$ using injectivity. Notice that $f(f(f(0)))=f(f(0))+0 = f(f(0))$. Apply the fact that $f$ is injective twice, and you'll find the value of $f(0)$ pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $(f\circ f)(x)=(f\circ f)(y)$ and $(f\circ f\circ f)(x)=(f\circ f\circ f)(y)$. So, $(f\circ f)(x)+x=(f\circ f)(y)+y$ but the previous equation yields $x=y$ so $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Say $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then we have $f(f(x_1)) = f(f(x_2))$ and $f(f(f(x_1))) = f(f(f(x_2)))$ so

$$x_1 = f(f(f(x_1))) -  f(f(x_1)) = f(f(f(x_2))) -  f(f(x_2)) = x_2$$

Say $a=f(0)$ and $b=f(a)$. Since we have $f(f(f(0))) = f(f(0))$ we have also $$f(f(a)) = f(a)$$ and $f(b) = b$. Now since f is injective and we have $$f(b)=b=f(a) \Longrightarrow a=b$$
So $$f(a)=b=a=f(0) \Longrightarrow a=0$$
So $f(0)=0$.